# TypeScript global declaration inside a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

There is Node.js script that contains a function that will be evaluated in browser and not in Node.js (stringified and sent to client side).

It reasonably triggers TypeScript type errors, because function body uses undefined variables that only exist in browser context:

```
// Node context
evaluateInBrowser(() => {
  // browser context
  window.foo(); // cannot find name 'window'
  localStorage.clear(); // cannot find name 'localStorage'
});
```

This is a frequent case in E2E frameworks (e.g. Protractor). `declare var window` isn't allowed to be placed into a function in TypeScript. And I'd prefer to not have it in Node.js context to avoid accidental use of browser globals there.

My intention is to

- keep the function anonymous *if possible*, because it is most readable as `evaluateInBrowser` argument
- keep the function a function, not a string
- avoid the pollution of Node.js global context with browser types (no `dom` TS library)
- avoid the pollution of Node.js module context with browser types (no `declare var window`) *if possible*
- type `window` and `localStorage` as `Window` and `Storage` respectively, not as `any` *if possible*

What are the options to fix this TypeScript problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to trick type checks with unused local variables:

```
  {
    let localStorage: { clear(): void };
    let window: { foo() };

    // Node context
    evaluateInBrowser(() => {
      // browser context
      window.foo();
      localStorage.clear();
    });
  }
```

They can be additionally wrapped with a block to avoid accidental use in Node context or collisions with other variables in this scope.